# Apply box shadow to a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate the following screenshot in css:

[image]

Firstly can this be done or will it I need to use an image?

I have the following [codepen](http://codepen.io/robbo/pen/gJpql) started which has the code:

```
<div class="module">
  <h2>Header</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui aspernatur sit perspiciatis debitis dolore impedit veniam illo dolorum tenetur eos eum placeat consectetur numquam error doloribus culpa ratione! Dolor voluptate!</p>
</div>

body {
  background:#f8f8f8;
  margin:40px;
}

.module {
  width:300px;
  background:white;
  padding:15px;
  border-top:5px solid orange;
  position:relative;
  &:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40%;
  }
}
```

The issue is the shadow at the bottom of the module...

edit: forgot to say this was a responsive box so no set widths.

Comment: What is the problem in Using this?

Comment: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/2WN73/) - Like this?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://matthamm.com/box-shadow-curl.html - I think it's **exactly** what you're looking for.

Comment: The box shadow in the sheenshot is uneven, not all the way around the div.

Comment: http://www.css3generator.com/ is your friend!

Comment: Good effort although nobody has completely replicated the screenshot yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the CSS3 `box-shadow` property.

**EDIT** I didn't notice you needed the shadow to only be at the bottom before.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kpzg4/3/

**EDIT 2** Incorporating oGeez's link for a better shadow.  Removed used of `:after` pseudo class for shadow as pseudo classes are required on a 'shadow' element in the DOM.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kpzg4/27/

Comment: Yup, but the issue is the box shadow is only needed fo the last portion of the box...

Comment: I think [the link](http://matthamm.com/box-shadow-curl.html) that oGeez provided is more accurate. Your example is almost there though.

Comment: Good effort, the shadow stops quite harshly and the background is an off white `#f8f8fa`

Comment: @RobMorris you just need to change some params on the shadow which I've added on the second edit in my post.  Also I've changed the colour although I'm sure you would have know how to do that.

Comment: Ive had a go using something similar although the layering isn't correct, z-index dosn't seem to work on absolute positioned elements http://jsfiddle.net/Kpzg4/26/

Comment: @RobMorris Looks fine to me - which browser are you in? Z-index works on elements positioned anything other than statically.

Comment: It's very faint, increase the rgba value and you'l see

Comment: @RobMorris there was no z-index on the shadow element.  I've added it (and left the aplha high for you to see) and it looks fine to me. http://jsfiddle.net/Kpzg4/30/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45456/discussion-between-richieahb-and-rob-morris)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow):

```
-moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
```

If you want to set the bottom shadow only then use this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 2px -2px #ccc;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 2px -2px #ccc;
box-shadow: 0 5px 2px -2px #ccc;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SXLJm/)

Answer (score 0):

A box shadow will work, but it will be the same shadow around the entire box, where as you need it just at the bottom corners.

A background image would probably be the easiest way to achieve this, and have it the background of a container div.

Comment: `background-image` is not a solution, if design is responsive!! :)

Comment: True, however oGeez posted a great link which achieves exactly the look the OP was after.